# Testing android app on python app-engine endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have my python app-engine endpoint running on localhost. How do I point my android app to it for testing? Right now, the android app is trying to access the `https:myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api` address on `appspot`. Must I first deploy the python endpoints server to `appspot` before the android app can see it? Could I just deploy the server to localhost and test android from there?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Sorry, I probably misunderstood your question. I think you should be able to test it locally as per this link - https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae. Step 5 & 6 refer to running back-end locally. Have you seen this page?

---

Yes, you have to deploy it to GAE. You can test your backend on GAE through API explorer, by https://mapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer to make sure its working fine. Then follow instructions from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android to generate android client.

There are some examples here as well,

**APP Engine backend**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python

**Android app using app engine backend**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android

Comment: Why is it that I can test on localhost when using the Google Eclipse Plugin for endpoints? I am referring to the default example that shows up when you first create an appengine connected android project with GEP. That backend is not deployed yet android sees it; the same is true for typical app-engine websites: I can test them on localhost fine.